# C++ convert int into string?

Tags: c++, string, compiler-construction, int

I tried to convert int into a string , but it doesn't work I dont know why...
here my Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <iostream>
#include <array>


using namespace std;


int main()
{
    struct Studentendaten {
        int matrnr;
        string name;
        string vorname;
        string datum;
        float note;
    };
    Studentendaten stud;
    array<Studentendaten,100> studArray ;   

  FILE * pFile;
  int ch; 
  int mnr;
  string sub;
  string sub1;
  string sub2;
  string sub3;
  string sub4;
  string sub5;

  int i = 0;
  int pos ;

  pFile=fopen("studentendaten.txt","r");  
  if (pFile==nullptr) 
  {
      perror ("Fehler beim öffnen der Datei");
  }
  else
  {       
    while (ch != EOF) 
    {
      ch = fgetc(pFile);
      sub += (char)(ch);
      pos = sub.find(";");
      if (pos != -1) 
      {
          sub1 = sub.substr(0,pos);       
          sub2  = sub.substr(pos+1,pos);
          sub3  = sub.substr(pos+1,pos);
          sub4  =sub.substr(pos+1,pos);
          sub5  =sub.substr(pos+1,pos);       
          mnr   =stoi(sub1);
          stud.matrnr = mnr;
          stud.name = sub2;
          stud.vorname = sub3;
          stud.datum = sub4
          stud.note = float(sub5);
      }
      if (ch == '\n') 
      {
          stud = {matrn,name,vorname,datum,note};
          studArray.[i] = stud;
          i++;
      }


      putchar(ch);
    }   
    fclose (pFile);
    }


  return 0;
}
```

I tried int mnr =stoi(sub1);
as well as int mnr = atoi(sub1); 
where sub1 = "029383214" something like that.... why does it not work? Compiler complains...

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want an int to a string or a string to an int?

Comment: `atoi` = ASCII To Integer.

Comment: Other than using `string`, your code is very C like.

Comment: The easiest way to convert between types is `boost:lexical_cast`.

Comment: Most of this code has nothing to do with the question. When you post code, reduce it to the smallest you can come up with that shows the problem.

Comment: I want convert string of numbers into an INT!

Answer (score 2):

Simply use a [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream):

```
int parse_int( const std::string& str )
{
    std::stringstream ss( str );
    int value;

    if( ss >> value )
        return value;
    else
        throw;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use boost::lexical_cast if I were on your place

```
string stringValue = lexical_cast<string>(101);
int intValue = lexical_cast<int>("101");
```

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use stringstream:

```
#include <sstream>
...

// int to string

int intVar = 10;

std::stringstream out;
out << intVar;
std::string converted = out.str();

// string to int

std::string src = "555";
std::stringstream in(str);

int result = 0;
in >> result;
```

And check [boost::lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::to_string(int)`.

[Reference.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)

Comment: I get an error when I use std::dateiLesen.cc:54:19: error: 'to_string' is not a member of 'std'       stud.matrnr = std::to_string(sub1);

Comment: @user2774480  You will need to upgrade your compiler to use the new `std::string` feature in C++x11

Comment: but I already entered for compiler: g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -c "%f" and for the make g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -o "%e" "%f"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::to_string` for simple cases or `std::stringstream` when you need more control over formatting (zero padding, hexadecimal etc.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int value = 19;

    cout << to_string( value ) << endl;

    stringstream s1, s2;
    s1 << setfill('0') << setw(4) << value;
    s2 << "0x" << hex << setfill('0') << setw( 8 ) << value;

    cout << s1.str() << endl << s2.str() << endl;
}
```